# jQuery selector: do not select input in div with given class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have this sample code:

```
<div class='root container'>
    <div>
        <input a ...>
        <input b .......>
        <submit submit1 doing some magic ajax... -> $(this).closest('div.container').find(':input') ==> a,b - not a,b,c,d>
    </div>
    <div class='container'>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input c ...>
                <input d .......>
                <submit submit2 doing some magic ajax... -> $(this).closest('div.container').find(':input') ==> c,d>
            <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inputs have no class to target. I want select input under `.container` but not inputs from nested `.container`.

Starting point is 'submit', where is `click()` action; I got `.container` (`$(this).closest('.container')`) and now I need know, how to select only input that are not nested:

If I'm on `submit1`, I get inputs `a, b`, not `a, b, c, d`. If I'm on `submit2`, I get `c, d`.

HTML structure may vary, so I cannot use accurate selectors (like div > input ,...).

Comment: Your question is about jQuery selectors, why does the title say CSS?

Comment: You don't have any `inputs` which are not descendants of `.container`

Comment: @Barmar sorry, too fast thoughts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, you point me right way - solution (and what I want in beginning) is in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auUx6/1/) :) :

```
var container = $('#submit-2').closest('div.container');
var result = $('#result');
container.children(':not(div.container)').find(':input:not([type="submit"])').each(function (k, v) {
    result.append($('<li/>').text('found: ' + $(v).attr('name')));
});
```

@billyonecan say right, that inputs are not descendants, so little google points me to another function - .children, that accepts selector as filter, so I am win :) - more in fiddle.

And - thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any `inputs` that are not descendants of `.container`, if you want to get all `inputs` inside of the `.root.container`, except those inside of child `.container`s, you could do something like this:

```
var $inputs = $('.root').find('input').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).closest('.container').length 
         || $(this).closest('.container').hasClass('root');
});
```

So you're finding all `input`s inside of `.root`, and then filtering them, returning only those which don't have an ancestor `.container`, or have an ancestor `.container` which is the `.root`.

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9dNa/9/)